# Passing code to Closure/Annoymous function dynamically

Tags: php

I wanted to create closure with dynamic code. To do that I wrote below code :-

```
 function generateFunction ($class, $method){
    $code = "require_once 'Init.php';";
    $code = '$model = new '.$class.'();';
    $code .= '$model->'.$method.'();';

    return function() use(&$code){
       return eval($code);
    };
}
```

I know eval is evil but unable to find any alternative yet.

To get the function in variable I used below code :-

```
$myNewFunction = generateFunction ('svn', 'update');
```

Now I want to run this function by passing it as argument to my PHP file. But this function has same body on the output while I expected it to be like below.

```
function(){return eval(require_once 'Init.php';$model = new svn(); $model->update())}
```

Basically this need arise when I decided to integrate the [Jobby](https://github.com/hellogerard/jobby).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically this need arise when I decided to integrate the Jobby.

I assume you want to create callback functions dynamically. Then your code is complete overkill and also doesn't need `eval` at all. You can get the same results by passing this as callback:

```
$callback = array(new SVN, 'update');
```

That's essentially all your code does anyway. Though with the difference that `SVN` is instantiated here, not when the callback is triggered. For an `eval`-free version of your code, this'll do:

```
function generateFunction($class, $method) {
    return function () use ($class, $method) {
         require_once 'Init.php';
         $model = new $class;
         return $model->$method();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete your answers, here is a complete example with jobby :

```php
$jobby = new \Jobby\Jobby();

$WebSitesSchedule = new WebSitesSchedule();
$WebSitesSchedule->load_all();

foreach ($WebSitesSchedule as $WebSiteSchedule)
{
    $Url = $WebSiteSchedule->ScheduleAction.'?'.$WebSiteSchedule->ScheduleParameters;

    $jobby->add( "CmsSchedule_".strval($WebSiteSchedule->ScheduleID), array(
        'command' => generateFunction($Url),
        'schedule' => $WebSiteSchedule->ScheduleCron,
        'output' => '/PATH/log/CmsSchedule.log',
        'enabled' => true,
        'debug' => true,
        'recipients' => 'toto@gmail.com'
    ));
}

function generateFunction($Url)
{
    return function () use ($Url)
    {
        $Result = Proxy::curl_request($Url);
        if($Result["status"]==="success")
        {
            print_r($Result);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($Result);
            return FALSE;
        }

    };
}

$jobby->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need to use `eval()`. You have to use `call_user_func` (or `call_user_func_array`) in conjunction with `class_exists` and `method_exists` instead.

```
require_once 'Init.php';
function generateFunction ($class, $method) {
    if (!class_exists($class)) return false;
    $model = new $class();
    return method_exists($model, $method)? array($model, $method) : false;
}

$myNewFunction = generateFunction ('svn', 'update');
if ($myNewFunction) call_user_func($myNewFunction);
```